# How can I mock (same request but different answers) requests with the response in Python?

Tags: python, mocking

I am trying to use Pythons mock package to mock Pythons requests module. What are the basic calls to get me working in below scenario?

I have a function that makes variety of requests.post() calls with different response each time
They have the **same URL**, changing only in the Body, they are performed sequentially, first a call and then another call

```
def myview(request):
  res1 = requests.post(("http://aurl",
                        body='[{"kind": "company"}]',
                        content_type="application/json"))
  res2 = requests.post(("http://aurl",
                        body='[{"kind": "people"}]',
                        content_type="application/json"))
```

In my test class I want to do something like this but cannot figure out exact method calls

Step 1:

```
# Mock the requests module
# when mockedRequests.post('aurl') with body "company" is called then return 'a response'
# when mockedRequests.post('aurl') with body "people" is called then return 'b response'
```

Step 2:

```
verify response contains 'a response', 'b response' , 'c response'
```

How can I complete Step 1 (mocking the requests module)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Rely on the order of the calls:

```
mocked_post.side_effect = ['a response', 'b response', 'c response']
```

2. Write a bit of business logic in the mock

```
MOCKED_POST_RESPONSES = {
  '[{"kind": "company"}]': 'a response',
  '[{"kind": "people"}]': 'b response'
}

mocked_post.side_effect = lambda url, body, content_type: MOCKED_POST_RESPONSES[body]
```

3. Or just use requests-mock module with a custom matcher https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/matching.html#custom-matching

Here is the decumentation on `Mock.side_effect`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect

Comment: Glad to help @ErnandesJunior! Feel free to accept the answer then. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer